# Error:Failed to resolve: :HERE-sdk:

Tags: gradle

I was trying to create a new project which has two flavor, and the `sdk` is independent of `app`.
So I modified these `build.gradle` files like below:

For the android lib module: `sdk`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        en
        zh
    }
    publishNonDefault true
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')
}

repositories {
    flatDir {//HERE SDK
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

For the android app module: `app`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cn.hudplay.testgradle"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        en
        zh
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    enCompile project(path:":sdk",configuration:"enRelease")
    zhCompile project(path:":sdk",configuration:"zhRelease")
    //compile(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')//this seems to be workaround if un-blocked
}

repositories {
    flatDir {//HERE SDK
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Then it told me `Failed to resolve ::HERE-sdk:`, and no other reasons..

I tried to move `Here-sdk` related gradle code to app's `build.gradle`, no more wrong.But I do need it in the `sdk` module..

What should I do..Anyone could help me?

*Workaround used temporarily :*
compile HERE-sdk for both `app` and `sdk`, no more wrong again. But I still feel something not right there...

Comment: I read the [android studio user guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#publish_multiple_variants) again..Then found something may help: AAR file include `/libs/someLib.jar` but maybe exclude `libs/someLib.aar`

Answer (score 1):

Hi HERE updated the documentation maybe that help you with the issue. I had the same problem too and it worked out following these steps here:

https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples

Comment: I'm no longer working on that project, anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me using the code above as an example (and if someone looks for a solution that works) was this approach:

copy the "\HERE-sdk\libsHERE-sdk.aar" file (dowloaded from your account on Here) to your \App\libs folder, then:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')
}
```

NOTE: what changes was only 2 lines: 
COMMENTED -> //compile(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar') and ADDED -> '*.aar' extension to array scope here -> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar']).

OBS: I know thi's an old question and maybe someone out there in this outside world must have already answered it, but I leave here my humble contribution. If someone wants to employ me, I'm looking for a job hehehe

Answer (score 0):

I got the aar compile without error by adding by adding it from

> Open Module Settings

`Step 1` , add the aar into app/libs folder

`Step 2`,  Right Click `App` and negative to `Open Module Settings`

[image]

`Step 3`, Click on `dependencies` on the left and then click on the `+` under `Declared Dependencies` 
[image]

`Step 4`, Select the `libs/HERE-sdk.aar` from the drop down and then click `OK`
[image]